# Why are empty statements legal?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, language-design

```cpp
int main()
{
    int var = 0;; // Typo which compiles just fine
}
```

In both C and C++, this is allowed because an *[expression-statement](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.expr#nt:expression-statement)* may be just a `;`, which makes it a "null statement". Why is this allowed?

Comment: get your hands on a microcontroller with a low count of timers, and soon you'll want to make use of NOP instructions... implemented with ; on C (C++ in this scenario is unlikely)

Comment: @R.A. a ;; is not a blank before a compiler optimization: it's a NOP.

Comment: @jpinto: Think you misread my comment.

Comment: Technically, this is not an empty expression (which C/C++ _does not_ allow), but the second semicolon is a null-expression. If for instance you want to do nothing in one of the branches of a conditional (ternary) expression (in void context), you are forced to write something useless (that moreover must match what is in the other branch).

Comment: I don't see any reason to *not* allow it. Any reasonable optimizing compiler will just discard the stray `;` and generate no code at all for it, so it does no harm and there are situations (like macros and auto generated code) where avoiding stray semicolons would be a pain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the way C and C++ express [NOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP).

Comment: Which is of prime importance on tight-budget microcontroller systems.

Comment: @jpinto3912: In fact `;` will almost certainly compile down to *no instructions at all*, rather than to the target platform's `NOP` instruction.

Comment: I doubt it. More likely to be an intrinsic, or asm. No instructions != NOP.

Comment: There is no way in C or C++ to express NOP and `;` certainly isn't it. You will need intrinsics or inline ASM for that. A stray `;` will just be optimized away to no instructions at all. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - "Express NOP" does not mean "translate into a NOP ASM instruction".

Comment: Then it's misleading. The primary meaning of NOP is an assembly or machine instruction, which is not relevant to this question. Despite the [wikipedia usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)#Code), using it for C++ is non-standard and rare; I've never come across it before in many discussions about C++ and other languages. Note every single comment on your answer thought you meant some relation to assembly/machine code.

Answer (score 35):

How else could `assert(foo == bar);` compile down to nothing when `NDEBUG` is defined?

Comment: Well, it occurs to me now that letting it compile down to something like `0` or `((void) 0)` would probably be fine too, but anyway...

Comment: assert() could be a macro and in NDEBUG reverts to an expression with no side effects, .e.g (void)0;

Answer (score 12):

You want to be able to do things like

```
while (fnorble(the_smurf) == FAILED)
    ;
```

and not

```
while (fnorble(the_smurf) == FAILED)
    do_nothing_just_because_you_have_to_write_something_here();
```

*But!* Please do not write the empty statement on the same line, like this:

```
while (fnorble(the_smurf) == FAILED);
```

That’s a very good way to confuse the reader, since it is easy to miss the semicolon, and therefore think that the next row is the body of the loop. Remember: Programming is really about communication — not with the compiler, but with other people, who will read your code. (Or with yourself, three years later!)

Comment: In my opinion, a much cleaner way to express such intent is to use `continue`: `while (fnorble(the_smurf) == FAILED) continue;` (preferably with the `continue;` statement on its own line — here it is not possible due to the formatting constraints of Stack Overflow comments). Another option is `do; while (fnorble(the_smurf) == FAILED);`, but I personally like it less.

Answer (score 10):

I'm no language designer, but the answer I'd give is "why not?" From the language design perspective, one wants the rules (i.e. the grammar) to be as simple as possible.

Not to mention that "empty expressions" have uses, i.e.

for (i = 0; i < INSANE_NUMBER; i++);

Will dead-wait (not a good use, but a use nonetheless).

EDIT: As pointed out in a comment to this answer, any compiler worth its salt would probably *not* busy wait at this loop, and optimize it away. However, if there were something more useful in the for head itself (other than i++), which I've seen done (strangely) with data structure traversal, then I imagine you could still construct a loop with an empty body (by using/abusing the "for" construct).

Comment: Will that actually wait? Can the compiler optimize away the loop since nothing happens?

Comment: Good question. Now that you mention it, I don't know. All I know is that it *should*. :)

Comment: @Tom: Good question. In C++ at least, according to the standard, execution time is not explicitly part of the "observable behaviour" of the system, so in theory I suppose a compiler could optimise this out. However, if i is volatile then this optimisation is forbidden.

Comment: " From the language design perspective, one wants the rules (i.e. the grammar) to be as simple as possible" - C++ lost that battle decades ago. But, I get what you mean ;)

Answer (score 10):

OK, I’ll add this to the worst case scenario that you may actually use:

```
for (int yy = 0; yy < nHeight; ++yy) {
    for (int xx = 0; xx < nWidth; ++xx) {
        for (int vv = yy - 3; vv <= yy + 3; ++vv) {
            for (int uu = xx - 3; uu <= xx + 3; ++uu) {
                if (test(uu, vv)) {
                    goto Next;
                }
            }
        }
    Next:;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the useful example: since goto labels must have a statement after them, but on the rare occasion you need a goto the label is often just needed at the bottom of a loop, so you need a NOP statement. You may rail against gotos, but it is occasionally preferable (AND more readable) to use a goto to exit deeply nested loops, rather than having extra variables and if() statements to exit each loop individually.

Answer (score 9):

I honestly don't know if this is the real reason, but I think something that makes more sense is to think about it from the standpoint of a compiler implementer.

Large portions of compilers are built by automated tools that analyze special classes of grammars. It seems very natural that useful grammars would allow for empty statements. It seems like unnecessary work to detect such an "error" when it doesn't change the semantics of your code. The empty statement won't do anything, as the compiler won't generate code for those statements.

It seems to me that this is just a result of "Don't fix something that isn't broken"...

Comment: DMR's  original C compiler (which is where this syntax comes from) was a recursive descent compiler - such compilers are normally hand written, so I don't think the toolds were an issue here.

Comment: That almost makes it seem *more likely* that this sort of thing would happen. If you are handcoding a r.d.p., then you are writing a function for every production in your grammar whose job is to match the next stretch of input... If expressions and other stuff make up statements, and both expressions and other stuff can end up consuming no input (except for the ultimate semicolon to follow), then the parser would recognize such statements. Idk if this is the real reason, but it seems like a reasonable way to reason it out. (I never wrote a huge r.d.p., but I have written one before).

Comment: I am looking now at one particular Yacc grammar for a C-like language, and the empty statement requires an extra rule, so the opposite seems to be true. At least with that grammar, for that language, for that tool.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, it is so that we can say things like

```
for (;;) {
  // stuff
}
```

Who could live without that?

Comment: That's not a good example, because, for example, the second semicolon is not used to end a statement. The second clause of the for is an expression; and leaving that empty is treated as a special case making it equivalent to true.

Comment: The original question was about expressions, not statements.

Comment: That's actually a poor and irrelevant example. The `;` inside the header of `for` have nothing in common with the `;` in the OP's question. What you have inside `for` header are not statements at all. And the `;` in the above `for` are not "empty statements". The `;` in `for` are simply hardcoded characters of `for` syntax with no special meaning. Only the first section of `for` header is referred as "statement" in the language spec, but even that one is a special kind of `for`-specific pseudo-statement with its own dedicated grammar.

Comment: ... In other words, the fact that `for(;;)` is legal has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that empty statements are legal. The two are described by their own, absolutely unrelated parts of the grammar and language spec.

Comment: And the original question is actually about statements, not expressions. The OP misused the term "expression" apparently because they haven't learned the difference between expressions and statements.

Comment: I can't believe 13 people +1ed this.

Answer (score 3):

When using `;`, please also be aware about one thing. This is ok:

```
a ? b() : c();
```

However this won't compile:

```
a ? b() : ; ;
```

Comment: That's because `;` cannot substitute for an *expression*; only for a *statement*.

Answer (score 3):

There are already many good answers but have not seen the productive-environment sample.

[Here](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/strlen.c?rev=1.7&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) is FreeBSD's implementation of `strlen`:

```
size_t
strlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *s;

    for (s = str; *s; ++s)
        ;
    return (s - str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common case is probably

```
int i = 0;
for (/* empty */; i != 10; ++i) {
    if (x[i].bad) break;
}
if (i != 10) {
    /* panic */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (1) {
    ;  /* do nothing */
}
```

There are times when you want to sit and do nothing. An event/interrupt driven embedded application or when you don't want a function to exit such as when setting up threads and waiting for the first context switch.

example:
http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.29/arch/m68k/mac/misc.c#L523

Comment: You don't need the semicolon there!

Comment: You could write while(1); And true, in some cases you do not need the ';' however that is not true with all compilers.  A fair amount of embedded compilers will yell at you if you are missing it.  However you are correct that in the ANSI C Grammar it is not required.