# Why doesn't ; ; result in a build error in VS?

Tags: c#, syntax

No matter how much ; you placed at the end of a C# code line, the compiler will not show an error and the build is successful.

In almost all other languages like C, C++ and Java. This is not allowed.

Comment: "in almost all other languages like c,c++ and java.. this is not allowed. " Really?

Comment: For the same reason blank lines don't cause a compiler error in Visual Basic.

Comment: What explanation? The language specs are written to allow it. Other langauge specs are not written to allow that. That simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly related to Eric's blog on why is this not a warning.

From Eric Lippert's blog " I am often asked why a particular hunk of bad-smelling code does not produce a compiler warning."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/03/danger-will-robinson.aspx

The point being, would it be good use of the compiler teams valuable time to introduce such a warning?

Answer (score 9):

Your contention that this pattern is illegal in C, C++ and Java is completely false.

I refer you to:

The C Programming Language, 2nd edition, section A9.2:

> ... the construction is called a null statement; it is often used to supply an empty body to an iteration statement...

The C++ Programming Language, 2nd edition, section r.6.2

> An expression statement with the expression missing is called a null statement; it is useful ... to supply a null body to an iteration statement ...

The Java Language Specification, 1st edition, section 14.5

> An empty statement does nothing.

The C# Language Specification, 4th edition, section 8.3:

> An empty statement is used when there are no operations to perform in a context where a statement is required.

Answer (score 6):

The empty statement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739(v=vs.71).aspx

No matter how many you have - still does nothing....

You can do the same thing in C/C++,  and probably Java too:

[Why are empty expressions legal in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824512/why-are-empty-expressions-legal-in-c-c)

Answer (score 1):

Why not? `;` delimits statements in many forms of code flow. A single `;` by itself simply means "nothing happens here". Putting a bunch of `;`s together still results in, well, nothing happening!

Answer (score 1):

`;` is an empty statement, and it's perfectly legitimate. What's your objection to having a series of consecutive `;`'s? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding multiple ; means you add empty statements. They are legal.

Answer (score 0):

Empty statements (a semicolon with nothing in front of it) are allowed in both C, C++, C#, and Java.

Answer (score 0):

It results in blank commands, that's all. Probably Microsoft decided to let their shiny language shoot blanks, if that's what the programmer wants. :)

The complier most probably is removing this/ignoring it altogether as part of optimization.

Comment: What should it ignore? There's literally nothing. It's very likely that the AST won't even contain any node for empty statements.

Comment: @delnan: The AST contains the empty statements. The compiler needs to generate NOPs so that breakpoints can be put on empty statements, and so that empty statements with labels have code that can be the target of a goto. If neither of those situations apply then we can trim the AST or optimize the IL so that the empty statements go away.

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider languages where newlines or whitespace is used to mark the end of a code block instead of semi-colons.  In these languages it's not an error to leave blank lines.