# Why are multiple semicolons allowed?

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
myBusiness business = new myBusiness();
business.DoWork(); ; ; ; ; ; ;
```

Why can we use multiple semicolons? Is it a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Why do you think this would be a bug? What would you expect the compiler to do in this case?

Comment: @BoltClock Because it’s never meaningful. A compiler could very well guard against it (at the expense of making it more complex, of course).

Comment: @KonradRudolph It could mean the ; key is sticking on your keyboard :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: So the compiler should decide that this is not meaningful even if it doesn't hurt? That would be work for nothing. I know what E.Lippert would say: "because it isn't worth the cost of designing, implementing, testing and documenting it".

Comment: You can see this for your answer (Binary Worrier's answer)-


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790771/does-c-sharp-allow-double-semicolon-if-so-are-there-any-special-ways

Comment: @Tim Like I said, it comes at a cost. I don’t advocate doing it, I’m just mentioning possible reasons to BoltClock’s question “why do you think this would be a bug?”

Comment: So frustrating to find bugs because of this when your having a lazy day and do `foreach(var s in something);`

Comment: Duplicate of: [why doesn't ; ; result in a build error in VS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5218164) and [Does C# allow double semicolon ; ; if so, are there any special ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4790771),

Comment: @Sayse: But you'll get a compiler warning then: "Possible mistaken empty statement" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x19t380(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Tim You are still trying to convince me of something that I’m already convinced of. You’re wasting your time.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I normally get a few lines down, trying to use my "s" in what I think is a foreach and then realise my mistake, become embarassed, and return to the kettle

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's because the semicolon, when used alone, represents the *empty statement*.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx) says:

> The empty statement consists of a single semicolon. It does nothing
>   and can be used in places where a statement is required but no action
>   needs to be performed.

And provides the following example:

```
void ProcessMessages()
{
    while (ProcessMessage())
        ; // Statement needed here.
}
```

Of course, you can execute as many empty statements as you want in sequence, and nothing will happen.

Comment: +1 you may wish to add an example such as for loop with "I" declared already

Comment: +1 because I had no idea.

Answer (score 7):

Semicolumn is an empty statement, means "do nothing".
Typical example when multiply semicolumns are required is an *infinite for loop*

```
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) { // <- ordinary for
    ...
  }

  for (;;) { // <- infinite (for) loop with no initialization, check and increment 
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The empty statement is valid in all C-derived languages. The most common idiomatic use is in a for statement, e.g.:

```
for (; ; )
{
}
```

OR

```
while (Method())
   ;
```

OR

```
void F() {
   //...
   if (done) goto exit;
   //...
   exit: ;
}
```

OR

```
if (true)
 {
      ;
 }
```

OR

```
if (true)
    ;
```

All statement are valid.

Comment: "OR" makes it sound like all of those snippets are equivalent, but they're quite different... And what exactly would be the point of `if (true) { ; }`?

Answer (score 1):

`;` is only a line terminator, which tells compiler that this statement is over.
If you are using multiple `;` in one line, the compiler will think they are multiple statements.

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon when used alone represents [empty statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Also, refer to the answers here - [Legal to allow multiple semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790771/does-c-sharp-allow-double-semicolon-if-so-are-there-any-special-ways) with nice detailed explanation that why its perfectly legal. Refer to answer by *[Binary Worrier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18797/binary-worrier)* explained for macros.

**From that post** -

You can redefine macros to be different to their initial definition, also you can redefine them so they don't exist at all.

Given an assertion macro `#define ASSERT(c) if(!c) throw new AssertionFailedException()` you can have your coded littered with ASSERT statements.

```
void Foo(int x) {
    int y = x + 2;
    ASSERT(y != 0);
   int z = x / y;
    . . . .
}
```

Now consider that you only want the asserts in debug builds, but not in release builds, for release you redefine the macro to be empty `(literally #define ASSERT)`. Now when Foo goes to the compiler for a release build, it looks like this

```
void Foo(int x) {
    int y = x + 2;
    ;
   int z = x / y;
    . . . .
}
```

There's now an empty statement where the ASSERT was, because there may or may not be a statement there (depending on build configuration), the compiler needs to be able to handle an empty statement.

Why this convention was kept in C# where there are nothing like C macros, I have no idea, but possibly because it causes little or no harm.

> I would guess that multiple ; are elided by the compiler before it
>   starts parsing code, therefore your unreachable ; is ignored by the
>   compiler.

Comment: The compiler doesn't have to elide them. What happens when you execute an empty statement? Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

';' stands for empty statement.

```
int a;;;;;; // this states that one statement and 5 empty statements
```

so there is no bug in this.