# Semicolons in a class definition

Tags: c++, syntax

I was reading [this gotw](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/086.htm) and here's a code sample from there:

```
struct X {
  static bool f( int* p )
  {
    return p && 0[p] and not p[1:>>p[2];
  };
};
```

The question was: how many errors should a compliant compiler give:

I answered one, because this code is equivalent to

```
struct X {
  static bool f( int* p )
  {
    return p && p[0] && ! p[1] > p[2];
  };
};
```

And I was thinking that a semicolon after a static function definition would be an error. But Mr. Sutter says 0 and explains (apart from the things I do understand) that

> The "extra" semicolon is allowed at
>   the end of a function declaration.

My question is:

- What text in the standard allows this?
- Does this refer to member functions only?
- Can a semicolon appear between two members or in any other place in a class definition as in

  ```
   struct X
   {
     int a;;;;int b; //Legal?
   };
  ```

Comment: Hehe, now that you can read deleted questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322007/c-puzzle-what-will-be-output-and-why :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, a semicolon is explicitly allowed after a function declaration in a class specifier. As a result, currently in the C++0x draft, the following is valid too: The first semicolon belongs to the function definition, the second to the class specifier delegating to the function-definition non-terminal.

```
struct A {
  void f() = delete;;
};
```

But three semicolons would be illegal. As are two semicolons after a function definition having a body. The respective text in the spec is the grammar at `9.2[class.mem]`.

Semicolons after function definitons were allowed already in C++03, but they were not allowed at namespace scope after function definitions. C++0x fixes that by introducing empty-declarations. But those only appear when you have a semicolon after function definitions outside class bodies.

Sutter talks about "extra" semicolons at the end of function *declarations* though, which is not entirely correct. Because the following is invalid syntax

```
struct A {
  void f();; // invalid!
};
```

An extra semicolon in a class specifier is only valid after a *function-definition*. Also, as a checkup at `9.2` uncovers, it's not valid when the function definition is a template

```
struct A {
  template<typename T> void f() { }; // invalid!
};
```

This is because it is parsed by a *template-declaration* (which will itself parse the remaining text to *function-definition* eventually) for which the class specifier does not have an additional `;` afterwards.

Comment: C++ has crazy syntax... Thanks, very much, Johannes :)

Comment: @Armen : Yeah really crazzzzzzyyyyy!! :D

Answer (score 1):

`;` is an empty statement. You can have as many empty statements as you want. It is absolutely correct.

```
int foobar(int arg)
{
    return 0;
};
```

is the same as

```
int foobar(int arg)
{
    return 0;
}
/*DO NOTHING*/;
```

Similar question: [Why are empty expressions legal in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824512/why-are-empty-expressions-legal-in-c-c)

Edit:

A declaration of a member is also a statement. So empty statement inside class is something like an << empty >> declaration statement inside class :)

Comment: yeah, ; is an empty statement, it's just that statements don't belong in a class definition

Comment: No, a statement is something that appears within a function definition.  Declarations within a function are statements, but a class member declaration is not a statement.

Comment: @aschepler: So what about definitions in global scope? Aren't they statements? They are not inside any function.

Comment: You can DO anything or nothing inside a function. You don't do anything inside a class, you declare things )

Comment: I understand what you mean from the beginning. This thing in C++ is just funny... stating to do nothing. But that's what it is apparently. BTW: Imagine, you made a typo and put two semicolons at the end of member declaration. And everything is OK. Now I know that C++ is forgiving! :D