# Linker error while implementing Adapter design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, adapter

I am getting linker error in the code below. 
If I make the ClientInterface's ClientAPI() function as pure virtual, then the linker error disappears.
What is the reason for this behavior?

```
    // How the interface looks like to the Client
class ClientInterface
{
public:
    virtual void ClientAPI();
    virtual ~ClientInterface(){}
};

template <class TYPE>   //this adaptor class can adapt to any type of legacy application as it is a generic function that uses template parameter to point to any legacy application
class Adaptor : public ClientInterface
{
public:
Adaptor(TYPE *objPtr, void (TYPE:: *fnPtr)())
{
    m_objPtr = objPtr;
    m_fnPtr = fnPtr;
}
void ClientAPI()
{
    /*....
    Do the conversion logic reqd to convert the user params into the params expected by your original legacy application...
    ....*/
    (m_objPtr->*m_fnPtr)(); //Would call the method of the legacy application internally
}
~Adaptor()
{
    if(m_objPtr)
        delete m_objPtr;        
}
private:
TYPE *m_objPtr; //You can keep either pointer to the Legacy implementation or derive the Legacy implementation privately by your Adaptor class
void (TYPE:: *m_fnPtr)();

};

//Adaptee classes below..
class LegacyApp1
{
public:
    void DoThis()
    {
        cout<<"Adaptee1 API"<<endl;
    }
};
```

//Execution class where main is defined and i have include the "Adaptor.h"

```
#include "headers.h"
#include "Adaptor.h"

void Adapter()
{
  ClientInterface **interface_ptr = new ClientInterface *[2];
  interface_ptr[0] = new Adaptor<LegacyApp1>(new LegacyApp1() , &LegacyApp1::DoThis);
  interface_ptr[1] = new Adaptor<LegacyApp2>(new LegacyApp2() , &LegacyApp2::DoThat);
  for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
  {
    interface_ptr[i]->ClientAPI();
  }
}

int main()
{
  //Testing();
  Adapter();

  char ch;
  cin>>ch;
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Can you modify your question to include the linker error you are getting?

Comment: your code should not compile for the semicolon at this line `virtual ~ClientInterface(){};`

Comment: @RakibulHasan Superfluous semicolons generally aren't problematic. (And, for better or worse, it compiles just fine in Visual Studio.)

Comment: @Lilshieste, but should not be relied on that, it is platform/compiler dependent and not portable

Comment: Not to get spun off on a tangent, but a semicolon after a function declaration is explicitly allowed. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365604/semicolons-in-a-class-definition

Comment: Without seeing the linker error, Interface classes should be pure virtual by definition

Comment: Also, pay attention that `LegacyApp1::DoThis` method is not static, therefore you can't pass it as an address to the `Adaptor` C-tor following the C-tor's declaration: `Adaptor(TYPE *objPtr, void (TYPE:: *fnPtr)())`

Comment: Hi All, Now I have answered my own question in a way as I know what went wrong then. I did not provide definition for the base class interface method, hence the linker error. Sorry for the silly error which costed so much time.

Comment: @dennis, if you have solved the problem post the answer here so other people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

So the correction in the above code is as follows: Just make the following changes to first few lines of the original code.

```
// How the interface looks like to the Client
class ClientInterface
{
public:
//earlier I forgot to define it, so it was giving linker error as  the function is just declared but not defined.
    virtual void ClientAPI(){} 
    virtual ~ClientInterface(){}
};
```

Thanks.