# Moving rvalue inside class member

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvalue, most-vexing-parse

I've been browsing for a while in search of an answer but I don't seem to find it. So I decided to specifically ask the question here.

I've been trying to use something like this (and variants hereof):

```
struct NonCopyable
{
    NonCopyable() { };
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable& other) = delete;
    NonCopyable(NonCopyable&& other) {  };
};

struct Host
{
    Host(NonCopyable&& nc) : m_nc(nc) { }
    NonCopyable m_nc;
};
```

to achieve this:

```
Host h(NonCopyable());
```

In other words, I'd like to construct NonCopyable inside the m_nc. Is this at all possible?

Comment: if you want to construct `NonCopyable` inside the `m_nc` then why do you want to pass it as as parameter (rather than constructing it inside `m_nc` ...?)

Comment: I'd like to inject it from outside. You mean that I should just pass the parameters of its constructor and have it constructed inside Host? Like: `Host(<parameters_for_NonCopyable>) : m_nc(<parameters_for_NonCopyable>)` ?

Comment: Some notes here on [semicolons after method definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5365656/211160).

Comment: :) Sorry about that.

Comment: _"Is this at all possible?"_ Did you try it? What made you think it might not be possible? Questions should include such details.

Comment: @underscore_d You're right. I had tried it unsuccessfully. Did not know about the most vexing parse issue and was assuming that something was wrong in the concept itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `nc` is an lvalue as a named parameter, you need to convert it to rvalue, e.g. via [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

```
Host(NonCopyable&& nc) : m_nc(std::move(nc)) { }
```

**EDIT**

There's a [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) issue. `Host h(NonCopyable());` is not a variable definition, but a function declaration; which declares a function named `h`, which returns `Host` and takes an unnamed parameter with type of function pointer (which takes nothing and returns `NonCopyable`).

Just change it to `Host h{NonCopyable()};`.

Comment: Yes, tried that too. Did not want to post it like that to not influence the answer.

Comment: @racanu You tried it, then what's the trouble? What makes you think it's impossible?

Comment: I mean that even with the std::move it doesn't work like I'd like it to. It compiles but I get a warning: 

`warning C4930: 'Host h(NonCopyable (__cdecl *)(void))': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)`

and there's no code generated for the instantiation line.

Comment: Really? `Host h(NonCopyable())` is a function declaration? Inside `main()`? Wow.

Comment: @racanu Yes, function declarations can be locally scoped, so that only the function in which the declaration occurs will be aware of the declared function. I'm not sure that's often practically useful, but it's an established thing.