# Use of null statement in C

Tags: c, syntax, use-case

What are typical uses of *null statement*

```
;
```

in C ?

I know that it is basically used to skip expression where it is expected by the compiler, but here I'm interested only in real-world examples of such use cases.

Comment: I prefer `{}` if you need an empty statement, it looks to me less likely to be accidental. So "never" ;-)

Comment: `{}` is not useful in some of the contexts `;` would be useful in.

Comment: @R..: which ones? As an empty statement, I mean - we've already got that in `for` statements you might write `(;` or `;;`, and since the parts omitted aren't statements (rather declarations or expressions), `{}` won't do. Obviously there are places in C where you can't just replace a semi-colon with `{}`. Almost all of them. But that's not what I meant :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are empty statements legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824512/why-are-empty-statements-legal)

Comment: @JanSchultke Scope of questions are a bit different. Your given question speaks about why C/C++ compiler doesn't give compile-time error on encountering empty statement, i.e. it's about C/C++ language design reasons behind that. While my question is about _best practical use-cases_ exploiting this language construct.

Comment: The dupe target is a [language-design] question and the answer to why the language allows it lies in the use cases. The scope of the questions is ever so slightly different, but the answers to one question may answer the other question, which is the standard for when something is a duplicate.

Comment: @JanSchultke Use-cases of a language designer may not overlap with use-cases of C/C++ compiler users. So, still I think that these are a different questions, although I may agree that partially those use-cases can match.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's typically the side-effect of a code block that was stripped by the preprocessor, like

```
#if DEBUG
    #define ASSERT(_x) Assert(_x)
#else
    #define ASSERT(_x)
#endif


ASSERT(test);    // Results in null statement in non-debug builds
```

That, or in loops where your condition already contains whatever needs to be done in each iteration.

Comment: There is a typo in the example: `Assert(x)` should be replaced by `Assert(_x)` since `_x` has been used as the parameter name (I can't edit the answer as edits must be at least 6 characters).

Comment: Also, for the `#else` case, I would rather use `#define ASSERT(_x) ((void) 0)` so that an error be reported when one forgets a semicolon, such as in: `ASSERT(test1) ASSERT(test2);` But in this case, there isn't a null statement any longer.

Answer (score 18):

```
while (*(dst++) = *(src++))
    ;
```

Answer (score 16):

After a label at the end of a function (or more precisely, at the end of any block), e.g.

```
void foo(void)
{
    // ...

exit:
    ;
}
```

Comment: I would totally put `return;` instead.

Comment: @steve The label can come at the end of any block, so `return` isn't always appropriate. An example is a multiply nested loop when you want to continue an outer loop from within inner loop (of course, you could use `label: continue; }` instead of `label: ;}`).

Comment: @Jim: or you could write `continue;` instead of `goto label;`. I believe there are uses for this, possibly even ones less crazy than, "I go to the label defined by some macro, hence I can't substitute continue in one special case". I just don't think I've ever seen one.

Comment: @Steve Please read what I wrote again: "continue an outer loop from within inner loop" -- just writing `continue;` would continue the wrong loop. The Bliss language had no goto but did have loop labels for break/continue of outer loops; too bad C doesn't have that.

Comment: @Jim: OK, I see. Yes, continuing an outer for loop requires a do-nothing statement. Loop labels are very rarely missed, but on the occasions when you do want one it's particularly annoying they aren't there, since it leads to silly arguments whether you should refactor into extra functions to avoid using "goto".

Answer (score 5):

```
while (somethingWithSideEffects()) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have used it, albeit rarely, in a possibly unusual situation (and one that some/many people would find wrong).  I have had to sometimes write a very complex `if` condition without an `else` clause where the if condition has to be negated.  Obviously it can be something like this:

```
if ( !( overly complex condition ) )
  {
  do stuff
  }
```

It sometimes makes more sense (to me at least) to think of it in terms of positive logic.  In other words, if the `overly complex condition` holds true, I don't want the code to run.  So I have instead written it as:

```
if ( overly complex condition )
  ;  // do nothing
else
  {
  do stuff
  }
```

Comment: I find it's better to break it down into multiple `if`. It's still going to be complex if you remove the `!( )`.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
 while (!kbhit())
     ;
```

Should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests for a compliant compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of `scanf` validation. `scanf` gets stuck when user didn't give the correct input. So, to prevent `scanf` from being stuck, characters until end of line must be removed.

```
if( scanf("%d",&integer) == 0 )
{
    while( getchar() != '\n' ) ;
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat unusual use -- but for which I *really* appreciate the existence of the null statement -- is when I have two conditions and two actions which I find I can most naturally express like this:

```
if(condition1)
     /* do nothing */ ;                                                      
else if(condition2)
     do_something;                                                           
else do_something_else;
```

Often `condition1` tests that everything is okay, but if it's not, `condition2` distinguishes between two different exception actions `do_something` and `do_something_else`.

This isn't the only way to express such a thing, of course.  It would be possible to repeat `condition1`:

```
if(!condition1 && condition2)
    do_something;                                                           
else if(!condition1)
    do_something_else;
```

But that seems inferior, because it repeats `condition1`.  Or it would be possible to use nested `if` statements:

```
if(!condition1) {
    if(condition2)
         do_something;                                                   
    else do_something_else;                                              
}
```

But of course nested `if` statements are notoriously prone to overcomplication and obfuscation, too.  So I often prefer the first version, with the null statement.

Answer (score 1):

The only uses I can think of are:

1- At the end of a loop, where the operations are already encoded within the loop statements. e.g. `while(a[i--]);`

2- At the end of a label, where no operation is needed to be done. e.g. `Label: ;`

Answer (score 1):

i was wondering how to write a null expression into the inline if and came up with this. it compiles and works.

```
condition ? x = 1 : "do nothing";
```

fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The only place I use null statements is when a `case` begins with a declaration:

```
switch(x) {
  case 5: ;
    int y = makeValue(z);
    ...
    break;
  ...
}
```

This will not compile if you remove the null statement that the case begins with. The reason is that a label cannot precede a declaration.