# Why the following do-while loop is valid?

Tags: c, loops, do-while

The loop is as follows:

```
do;
while(1);
```

Why the above loop is not giving a syntax error?

#### I am using mingw gcc compiler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code looks like it was written to obfuscate its meaning but if we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.8.5` *Iteration statements*, the grammar for do while is:

```
do statement while ( expression ) ;
```

and *statement* can be an *expression statement* which in turn can be a *null statement* which is what `;` is. So it is the same as:

```
do
  ;
while(1);
```

we can see from section `6.8.3` *Expression and null statements* paragraph *3* says:

> A null statement (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no operations.

Answer (score 6):

```
do
    ; //nop
while(1);
```

Now it is more readable :)

---

Note that the `;` is a [Null Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599380/use-of-null-statement-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

This is a single statement do-while loop equivalent to

```
do
    no_op(); // do nothing
while (1);
```

or

```
do {
}
while (1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I hate null statements and I'd be perfectly happy to have them removed from the standard.

My preferred form would be

```
do continue;
while (1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is an infinite loop with an empty statement `;`.

```
do
{
   ;

}while(1);
```