# Adding a `;` at the end of while loop

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=5;
    while(i--)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    };
    printf("Out of loop\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine! Does `;` at the end of a loop not mean anything?
So even if we add it, we don't have any problems? Just curious! I think adding `;` at the end of a loop doesn't make any sense.

Comment: the extra `;` is the termination of an "empty statement". Adding `;;` after the `}` would add two empty statements.

Comment: Note that, in `do { /* code */ } while ( /* condition */ );`, the trailing `;` is *not* an empty statement, but required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It "works", but it's an empty statement so it changes the structure of your program.

Consider this:

```
if (foo())
  while (bar())
  {
    foo_some_more()
  }
else
{
  do_something_about_it();
}
```

The above works since the `while` is a single statement, and thus the `else` is still able to "find" the `if` properly. If you add a semi-colon after the `while`-loop's closing brace, you break that structure and it will no longer compile.

So, although empty statements can look harmless, they are not so they really should be avoided. Plus: they add pointless confusion to the code, of course.

Answer (score 6):

The `;` here is considered as an empty statement or null statement.

Sample

```
int i = 0;;
```

For more information, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5599380/3137699) question.

<sup>Word of Caution: Don't consider this as a thumb rule. There are cases where the representation may **appear** same, but they are not null statement but part of a syntax. Example: `do..while` loop</sup>

Answer (score 4):

A superfluous `;` is an empty statement and is redundant in this particular instance.

One instance where you're *required* to use an empty statement is in a `switch` to a final branch that does nothing:

```
switch (expression)
{
    case 1:
       /*Some statements here or empty*/
    case 2:
    ;  /*A statement is required between here and the closing brace
         An empty statement will suffice.*/
}
```

You ought to avoid using superfluous empty statements; they can emit bugs (particularly if you enclose your code in `if` statements during a refactoring effort), and older compilers will complain. Using excess semicolons in macros is particularly pernicious.

Comment: Errr... how is the semicolon required there?

Comment: Try compiling without it ;-)

Comment: I put in another case. Principle still holds though.

Comment: @DevSolar True, but there must be a statement between the last case and the closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

These are Perfectly Valid, They are called Empty statements,They do nothing.

```
int main()
{
  ;
  ;
  ;
  ;
  {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by various users above, the relevant semi-colon is an empty statement and has no effect.

This however is a slightly different story:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=5;    
    while(i--); //<--- Put the semi-colon here and see what you get.
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }    
    printf("Out of loop\n");    
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i=5;
    while(i--)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }/*blank statement*/;
    printf("Out of loop\n");
    return 0;
}
```

it's just a blank statement.
above The braces itself tells end of the block so then it would treat the ; as blank stament