# Why is a semicolon by itself allowed in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, language-lawyer

Why does the C/C++ parser not report an error on a semicolon when it is used alone? For example:

```
int a;
;
int b;
```

Is it a consequence of language grammar rules or is it a consequence of parsing algorithms? What do standards say about such a case? Whether `;` or e.g. `int;` should be allowed?

Comment: `int;` is not allowed since the definition misses an identifier.

Comment: Why shouldn't `;` be allowed?

Comment: `;` is the *empty statement*

Comment: Doing nothing is not illegal in C++. :)

Comment: And also interesting answers in the very similar [Use of null statement in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599380/use-of-null-statement-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the classic string copy function from K&R:

```
void strcpy(char *src, char *dst)
{
    while (*src++ = *dst++);
}
```

As you can see the empty statement is not just legal, it's one of foundations of the short C syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also _really terrible code_, and should have `{}` instead, so I'm not convinced this is a great example.

Comment: This is not the example, this is the citation from K&R.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your answer is "empty statements are allowed in part because K&R wrote this crap code that uses them, which could and should have been written another way". Is that it? I just don't see how citing a use of `while (...);` is an answer here.

Comment: Without empty statement this code would have been impossible. But it's possible, and it's promoted as an example of a right C style by the authors of C.

Comment: "Impossible"? What's wrong with the superior `while (*src++ = *dst++) {}`? (I don't care whether the authors of C thought this was "a right C style" decades ago; it's inferior, and that's a common notion nowadays)

Comment: `{}` is not described in K&R. :)

Comment: Right, that's kind of my point. It's much better code, and K&R don't mention it, therefore referencing K&R doesn't really prove that the semicolon-terminated empty statement is needed!

Answer (score 1):

A semicolon terminates a statement.

If your statement doesn't do anything, that's your prerogative as a programmer.

An example of a completely valid use of an empty statment:

```
 for (int x = 0;; x++) {
     if (something(x)) {
         return 5;
     }
     if (bah(x)) {
         continue;
     }
     if (otherthing(x)) {
         return 3;
     }
 }
```

The middle statement in the `for` loop is empty. But it is still necessary, as the `for` loop takes three distinct statements, and the first and third are populated.

I don't see a good reason why a lone semicolon should be invalid; it does no harm. It is allowed by all relevant C/C++ standards, which is not a worse position than it not being allowed.

Comment: 1. **Is it** allowed by all standards? (even pre-C++11?) IIRC it's not.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore At the top of the loop. `for (int x = 0;; x++)`. Note the double semicolon.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - the empty statement is in `for (int x = 0;; x++)` - note the two semi-colons consecutively, this is an empty statement.  As far as I know, the example given in the answer has been valid in all C and C++ standards, as well as K&R.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore If it not allowed by C98, then I've never seen a conforming compiler in my entire life. I have yet to have a program rejected because it contains an extra semicolon at the end of a line.

Comment: Ah, missed the loop condition, my bad.

Comment: empty statement within for loop is legal even in K&R. As a side note, inline `int` declaration is not.

Comment: I hate to say it, but your for-loop does not contain an empty (null) statement. It merely contains a missing condition. To see it, consider that you cannot put statements there (but only conditions which are expressions or declarations whose type can convert to booleans). What is similar is merely that both in the null statement and the missing condition, an expression that is optional is missing, but that's about it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Perhaps I should have left the first one blank, then. That doesn't have to be a boolean...

Comment: litb's right; this example is wrong.

Comment: for (int x = 0; true; x++) {} is more readable imho

Answer (score 0):

It's specified in the standard, **§6/1** and **§6.2/1** (revision N3376):

> statement:
>
> ...
>
> attribute-specifier-seq_opt expression-statement
>
> ...

and

> expression-statement:
>
> expression_opt;

So a statement can be an expression statement with a colon and optionally a expression and an attribute specifier sequence before.