# What is a null statement in C?

Tags: c, null

I want to know exactly, what is a null statement in C programming language? And explain a typical use of it.

I found the following segment of code.

```
for (j=6; j>0; j++)
;
```

And

```
for (j=6; j>0; j++)
```

Comment: An example might be `while (1 == 1) ;` which loops forever doing nothing. Use it, for instance, in a thread which you do not want to terminate, which might continue to process messages which it receives, or hanldle interrupts, or have its callback functions called by other processes.

Comment: Closed -- unclear? Booo. Ok so the question shows lack of research but that doesn't justify closing it with an incorrect reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of null statement in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599380/use-of-null-statement-in-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the **msdn** page:

> The "null statement" is an expression statement with the expression missing. It is useful when the syntax of the language calls for a statement but no expression evaluation. It consists of a semicolon.
>
> Null statements are commonly used as placeholders in iteration statements or as statements on which to place labels at the end of compound statements or functions.

know more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zea45ac.aspx

---

> And explain a typical use of it.

When you want to find the index of first occurrence of a certain character in a string

```
int a[50] = "lord of the rings";
int i;

for(i = 0; a[i] != 't'; i++)
    ;//null statement
//as no operation is required
```

Answer (score 6):

A null statement is a statement that doesn't do anything, but exists for syntactical reasons.

```
while ((*s++ = *t++))
    ; /* null statement */
```

In this case the null statement provides the body of the while loop.

or (disclaimer: bad code)

```
if (condition1)
    if (condition2)
        dosomething();
    else
        ; /* null statement */
else
    dosomethingelse();
```

In this case the inner else and null statement keeps the outer else from binding to the inner if.

Answer (score 4):

From C11, [§6.8.4.1, 6.8.3 Expression and null statements](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.3p3):

> A null statement (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no
>   operations.

The standard also provides a couple of common uses of it:

> EXAMPLE 2 In the program fragment
>
> ```
>       char *s;
>       /* ... */
>       while (*s++ != '\0')
>               ;
> ```
>
> a null statement is used to supply an empty loop body to the iteration
>   statement.
>
> 6 EXAMPLE 3 A null statement may also be used to carry a label just
>   before the closing } of a compound statement.
>
> ```
>       while (loop1) {
>             /* ... */
>             while (loop2) {
>                     /* ... */
>                     if (want_out)
>                             goto end_loop1;
>                     /* ... */
>             }
>             /* ... */
>       end_loop1: ;
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A null statement doesn't **DO** anything, hence the solo '**;**'

*so....this code block will do nothing 10x in C/C++*

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){//execute the following 10 times
   ;//nothing aka "null statement"
}//end for
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the null statement serves.  In the "old days" the math hardware might not return an integer value when you needed one, such as returning 0.999... as sin(pi / 2), (that is sin(90 degrees)).

```
int i, j, k;
i = something;
for(j = 1; (2 * j) <= i; j *= 2);
```

Computes in j the largest integer power of 2 less than i.  Not very efficient for large i but useful if you could not trust Log functions to return an exact integer value.

My C++ compiler does not accept the null statement as a function body, but does accept the "empty statement" which I think is just an empty statement block "{}".

Answer (score 0):

Whether C or java, null has a special significance.
Whenever there is a need of re-intializing of values to variavle, null serves the purpose.

If there is a String i, and we want it to add a char value through a loop, then first we have to intialize i with null.

Comment: The OP's question was about null ***statements***, rather than the null ***keyword***, which is what your answer appears to address.