# Could you please explain why the value of i variable is 3 here after getting executed?

Tags: c, while-loop, post-increment, postfix-operator

The semicolon has been added after the first while loop, but why is the value of the `i` variable `3` here, where `j` is `2`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=1;
    while(i++<=1);    
    printf("%d",i);  
    int j=1;
    while(j++<=1)
        printf("%d",j);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you notice the semicolon after the first `while` and its absence after the second one?

Comment: @user3121023 But why the value of j is getting incremented again?

Comment: i is incremented after the test fails.

Comment: Always use `{}` for the scopes, do not use the implicit ones created automatically.

Comment: but if you have many one liners than the way without `{}` is more readable and takes way less space. And it's cooler

Answer (score 2):

Both `while` loops run once (and once only); the difference is that, in the second case (the `j` loop) you are printing the 'control variable' *inside* the loop but, for the first case, you are printing it *after* the loop condition has evaluated to `false`. Also note that, in the first case, the semicolon immediately following the `while` statement defines the body of that loop as empty<sup>1</sup>.

Let's break down the first loop into steps:

- On the first test of the condition, `i++` evaluates to `1` **and then** `i` is incremented – so the loop runs.
- On the second test, `i++` evaluates to `2` (so the loop doesn't run) but `i` is still (post-)incremented, leaving it with the value of `3` (as shown in the output).

The same thing happens with `j` in the second loop but, in that case, as previously mentioned, you are displaying the value in the body of the loop (on its only run), so you see the value after the first (post-)increment.

As noted in the comments, if you add another `printf("%d", j);` *after* the body of the loop (which, in that case, consists of a single statement), you will see that `j`, too, has the value `3` when that loop has finished.

---

<sup>1</sup> More precisely, the semicolon (on its own) defines a [*null statement*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40440400/10871073), which forms the body of the `while` loop.

---

It is often helpful to clarify such 'null loops' by putting the semicolon on a line by itself (some compilers, with full warnings or static analysis enabled, may even suggest you do this):

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i++ <= 1)
        ; // Body of loop - Null Statement
    printf("%d", i); // Loop has finished
    int j = 1;
    while (j++ <= 1)
        printf("%d", j); // Body of loop
    // Loop has finished
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters let;s consider how the postfix increment operator works. From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the
> operand**. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
> incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
> it).

Now consider this while loop

```
int i=1;
while(i++<=1);
```

In the first iteration of the loop the value of the expression `i++` as the value of its operand that is `1`. So the loop will iterate a second time, Due to applying the side effect to the variable `i`  it will be equal already to 2 when the expression `i++<=1` will evaluate the second time.

Now the value of `i` is equal to `2` and is greater than `1`. so the loop will be interrupted. Again due to applying the side effect of the postfix increment operator to the variable `i` it will be equal to `3`. This value is outputted in the following call of `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the semicolon in the end of the while you will take: `i = 3` and `j = 3`(IN THE OUTPUT).

If you add the semicolon only in the end of the printf and not to the while you will take `i = 2` and `j = 2`(IN THE OUTPUT), but in the end you will, also, have the values
`i = 3` and `j = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

In simplest terms,

consider three things for each iteration of first while loop:

first iteration:

```
int i = 1;//initialization  

while(i++<=1); //1. i evaluated as 1, 
               //2. loop condition is true causing loop to iterate again. 
               //3. ...but not before ++ causes i==2.
```

second iteration:

```
while(i++<=1); //1. i evaluated as 2,
               //2. loop condition is false causing loop to eventually exit
               //3. ...but not before ++ causes i==3.
```

`printf` is not included in the `while` loop (because of the semicolon) but
when program flow finally reaches `printf("%d",i);` the value of `i` is output as `3`

In the second loop, because `printf` *is* included in the `while` construct, it will output the value of `j` for each iteration.   For the same reasons as in loop one, it will also iterate only twice, and its values at time of output will be `2` & `3`.

[Using a debugger](https://u.osu.edu/cstutorials/2018/09/28/how-to-debug-c-program-using-gdb-in-6-simple-steps/) to set *break points*, and a *watch* on `i`, you can step through code such as this to see the sequence of these effects as they happen.

Answer (score 0):

For explanation porpouses look at this example:

```
int main()
{
    int i=1;
    while(i++<=1)
       printf("%d",i);     
    printf("%d",i); 
}
```

The Output is:

```
2
3
```

Ok let's dive into the programm procedure:

1. Declaring i (i = 1)
2. while checking Condition and it's true because i++ returns 1(old Value). That's because the ++ are after the i. If you would code it like this ++i than it returns 2(new Value) (i = 2)
3. execute printf (i = 2)
4. while checking Condition and it's false because i++ returns 2 and 2 is not <= 1 (i = 3)
5. execute printf (i = 3)

Do you understand?

If it solved your thoughts jumble ;) mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've got many answers already so I won't try to explain it in words but with an illustration in code. I've added two functions:

- One that acts like a prefix increment operator (`++i`)
- One that acts like a postfix increment operator (`i++`)

I'm only using the postfix version in the program though. I've added logging to the function so you can see how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// this acts as if you put ++ before the variable
int preinc(int* p) { 
    ++*p;
    return *p;
}

// this acts as if you put ++ after the variable
int postinc(int* p) {
    int rv = *p;
    ++*p;
    printf("returning %d but incremented to %d\n", rv, *p);
    return rv;
}

int main() {
    int i=1;
    while(postinc(&i) <= 1);    
    printf("end result: %d\n---\n", i);

    int j=1;
    while(postinc(&j) <= 1)
        printf("in loop: %d\n", j);
    printf("end result: %d\n", j);
}
```

Output:

```
returning 1 but incremented to 2
returning 2 but incremented to 3
end result: 3
---
returning 1 but incremented to 2
in loop: 2
returning 2 but incremented to 3
end result: 3
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because the "i" variable is incremented only after the first iteration of the loop, in which the empty statement (terminated by the semicolon) is evaluated.
that is why it is highly recommended to do "++i" rather than "i++", because then the incrementation is performed prior to the evaluation.
if you flip it here, you will see that i will be equal to 2 as well, regardless of the presence of the semicolon

Comment: "_the "i" variable is incremented only after the first iteration of the loop_" - Not quite right. It's incremented after the evaluation of `i++` (which has the unincremented value) and `i` will carry the incremented value inside the loop.