# Is it portable to have a stray semicolon in a class' declaration

Tags: c++, class, syntax, language-lawyer, grammar

```
class Test
{
  ;
  int x;
};
```

Is this perfectly legal and portable?

Comment: A stray semicolon is just an [empty expression](http://ideone.com/q0uDc "Empty expression example"). So it should be legal and portable, although I don't recommend it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824512/why-are-empty-expressions-legal-in-c-c

Comment: @Zeta: Indeed.  But are expressions permitted in the above context?

Comment: @Oli: I don't think so. Only declarations (and `static_assert`) are allowed inside a class definition, not expressions. Member initializers can of course have expressions, but that doesn't apply here. Also, if that is parsed as a declaration, it's illegal since declarations that don't declare anything are ill-formed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my reading of the standard, this is not allowed.

If you look at the grammar definition only, it seems to allow it. The relevant parts are:

The *member-specification* is what appears between the `{ ... }` in the class declaration.

*member-specification* is a sequence of *member-declaration* and access specifiers. One possible form for a *member-declaration* is:

> *attribute-speciﬁer-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *decl-speciﬁer-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *member-declarator-list*<sub>opt</sub> ;

Since everything before the semicolon is optional, it looks like it's allowed to have an empty 
 *member-declaration*, which consists of only a semicolon.

However, 9.2/1 says:

> Except when used to declare friends (11.3) or to introduce the name of a member of a base class into a derived class (7.3.3), member-declarations declare members of the class, and **each such member-declaration shall declare at least one member name of the class**.

Since an empty member-declaration does not declare at least one member of a class, it seems that this is not standard-compliant, even if some compilers accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++14, yes. The grammar for a *member-declaration* may now be an *empty-declaration*, which is always just the token `;`. The C++14 wording saying that ordinary declarations in a class definition must declare something reads:

> Except when used to declare friends (11.3), to declare an unnamed bit-field (9.6), or to introduce the name of a member of a base class into a derived class (7.3.3), or when the declaration is an *empty-declaration*, *member-declaration*s declare members of the class, and each such *member-declaration* shall declare at least one member name of the class.

This has since been reorganized into a list of non-member syntax options in [[class.mem]2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#general-2), still including *empty-declaration* as a valid piece which doesn't declare anything.