# In C, can the expression foo() be used as the empty expression if foo's return type is void?

Tags: c, return, void, undefined-behavior

With respect to the return statement, the Microsoft Visual Studio documentation says

> Syntax:
>
> return *expression*;

where expression is marked as optional. It continues

> The value of expression, if present, is returned to the calling function. If expression is
>   omitted, the return value of the function is undefined.

This is quite clear, but on the other hand, there is the notion of an empty expression. This makes me confuse. Thinking of the empty expression not as nothing, but as an expression which is empty, I would think that if we have a function

```
void foo(void)
{
     return;
}
```

then the expression foo() could be used wherever the empty expression is allowed. For example, the behaviour of the code

```
unsigned int i=0;
for(foo();i<10;i++) printf("%u",i);
```

would be defined.
I am aware that this is probably of little practical relevance, but I would like to understand why, in this context, the empty expression is not an expression.

Comment: "*... there is the notion of an empty expression ...*" **where** is this notion and where does it come from?

Comment: Hmmm, that's probably a good point. I read about this on stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824512/why-are-empty-expressions-legal-in-c-c

In addition, I read about the null statement and assumed that the empty expression is the corresponding expression. 

Are you saying that actually empty expressions are not defined in C?

Comment: @lee77 Yes, he's saying that and he's most probably right about that.

Comment: I just got it from Yu Hao's answer. It's called void expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called **void expression**. And you can use a void expression in `for` like you did. The void expression does nothing but its side effect, which is calling the function.

In fact, if the first clause of `for` is any type of expression, it's evaluated as a void expression:

> #### C99 6.8.5.3 The `for` statement
>
> ... If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.

and

> #### C99 6.3.2.2 `void`
>
> The (nonexistent) value of a void expression(an expression that has type `void`) shall not
>   be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to `void`) shall not be
>   applied to such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void
>   expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its
>   side effects.)

Comment: Thanks to all, and sorry for spreading the apparently undefined term of an "empty expression". I won't change the question since maybe some day someone thinks the same way I did. 
So the *return value* of foo is undefined, but since the call `foo()` in the above for loop is evaluated as a void expression, its value is thrown away, thus the behaviour of the for loop is defined. And the statement `return;` within the definition of `foo` is just a statement that doesn't contain any "empty" expression.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there actually is such a thing in C as "the empty expression", but if there is, then you are confusing it with the type `void`, **and** at the same time you are confusing the act of returning "nothing" from a non-`void` function (which is illegal) with leaving out the initializer expression of a `for` loop (which is legal).